# Appium - Check if element exist

Tags: c#, selenium, appium

I am trying to check if an element exist or not in my application (React Native) with Appium (C#). I beleive using `.Displayed` is the best practice for this, however, this throws an `NoSuchElementException` when the element does not exist.

The only workaround I can think of for this is to wrap the `.FindElement*` method with a `try/catch`. Is this the best method for checking if an element exist, or am I missing a better approach?

[image]

```c
private AndroidElement Name => Driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@text='John Doe']");

public void OpenMenu()
{
    Utils.Log("Opening menu");
    if (!Name.Displayed)
        ToggleButton.Click();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add a tag for the programming language you are using... looks like C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Displayed` tells you whether the element is *visible*, not present/exists. The reason it's throwing is because when the element is not there, your `.Find*` fails. You would also get false negatives if the element was present but not visible. Best practice in cases like this is to use the plural form of `.Find*`, e.g. `FindElementsByXPath()`, and check to see if the collection is empty. If it's not empty, the element is present.

```
private IEnumerable<AppiumWebElement> Name => Driver.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@text='John Doe']")
```

Then to check if the collection is empty

```
// requires LINQ
if (Name.Any())
{
    // element exists, do something
}
```

If you don't want to use LINQ

```
if (Name.Count() > 0)
```

Per the [Appium docs](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/find-elements/), you should avoid using XPath.

> XPath | Search the app XML source using xpath (not recommended, has performance issues)